# Как правильно вывести данные? PHP + MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется две таблицы:

```
1) item_cat ['id','name','status']
- 1, Товар, 1
- 2, Продукт, 1
- 3, Отход, 1
2) item_debit ['id','name','value']
- 59, Владимир, 100.00руб
- 60, Владимир, 200.00руб
- 70, Алексей, 0.00руб
- 80, Владимир, 60.00руб
- 90, Дмитрий, 400.00руб
....
```

и сессия юзера (пример Владимир $_SESSION['user_name'] = 'Владимир')

как foreach-ом вывести данные из двух таблиц где имя (name) в item_debit равняется WHERE name='$_SESSION['user_name']'), и чтобы получилось следующее:

В профиле Владимира:

```
Товар - 100.00 руб
Продукт - 200.00 руб
Отходы - 60.00 руб
```

сделал вывод использовал две foreach но данные максимально продублировались по количеству значений. в обоих бд нет никакаких данных по которым можно было бы связать, вывод происходит по сортировке с меньшего IDnum к большему, таким образом если у Владимира в таблице item_debit всего одна запись то в профиле должно получиться вывод:

Профиль Владимира (если в item_debit одно упоминание имени):

```
Товар - значение из поля item_debit
```

.. остальные из item_cat не выводятся (продукт, и отходы не выводятся из-за того что одно упоминание имени в другой таблице -> item_debit)

Comment: Чтобы правильно вывести данные, их надо сначала правильно ввести. При занесении в таблицу item_debit надо добавлять id из таблицы item_cat. А лучше сделать в item_debit нормальные колонки вида user_id, raw, product, waste и писать на каждого пользователя одну строку

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, чтобы связать таблицы надо иметь общее поле. Добавляем в таблицу item_debit поле cat_id, они должны совпадать с item_cat.id

Забирать данные с нескольких таблиц поможет join

```
SELECT * FROM item_debit as d LEFT JOIN item_cat as c ON d.cat_id = c.id;
```

Подробнее о join [тут](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

В случае если вы хотите выводить категории даже при отсутствии соответствующей строки в item_debit, то подойдет RIGHT JOIN

Comment: вот именно причина в том что немогу добавить целенаправленно, данные выгружаются из другого бд без какой либо привязки, по сути две таблицы с двух разных серваков

Comment: и по какому принципу вы хотите их связать?

Comment: for ($i = 1; $i < count($table1); $i++) {
    echo $table1[$i]['name'] + ' - ' + $table2[$i]['value'];
} так чтоли?

Comment: по тому приниципу что в таблице item_cat и item_debit данные занесены по порядку, по ASC выведет все 3 Владимира по возрастанию ID записи, item_cat также c по возростанию, те Первый Владимир - равно - Товар, Второй Владимир - равно - Продукт, Третий Владимир - равно - Отходы